# need to copy war file from local machine to amazon ec2 instances

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, tomcat

Hi I have created an amazon ec2 instance and now I need to deploy my java/j2ee based web app. I have apache tomcat6 running. I am managing the server via ssh in terminal. I need to copy war files to the server through how do I do that. I am newbie kindly help m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy).

Comment: I tried rsync I used this command rsync -avz filename.war instance_key.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps and I also tried rync -avz filename.war ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps from both remote terminal and local terminal but its not working I am getting an error which says permission denied (public key)

Comment: This may help; http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html